# nodejs & postgres : best way to do select for update

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, cursor

I need to do 'select for update' in postgres database from node.js, i.e obtain a cursor, iterate on it and updating values if needed.

I don't know if it is even possible in node.js and how.

I have found https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-cursor which seems good for reading cursor, but nothing for updating it.

Is there a module or pattern that can achieve this ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, there is no implementation for this within Node JS platform, so your only viable option is to implement it within a Postgres function and then just call it from Node JS.

Answer (score 1):

Update from 2023:

You are now able to do this for example with the pg-package and a lock on row-level.

```
class DBConnector {
constructor(){
    const { Client } = require('pg');
    this.client = new Client({
        user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        database: process.env.DATABASE,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
      });
    this.client.connect();
}

async acquireLockForRow(table, rowId) {
    await this.client.query('START TRANSACTION');
    try {
        // If it is locked, it throws an error
        const res = await this.client.query('SELECT id FROM ' + table + ' WHERE id=' + rowId + ' FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;');
        
        // If there is no lock
        if (res.rows[0].id === rowId) {
            // Release the lock after 5 minutes (if not already done, just to avoid forgetting to unlock it)
            setTimeout(async () => {await this.releaseLock()}, 1000 * 60 * 5);
        }
    } catch(e) {
        return "Could not obtain";
    }
}

async releaseLock() {
    await this.client.query('COMMIT;');
}
}
```